# Why am I getting a Null Pointer Exception from this Java code?

Tags: java, jdbc

I have a method ... where I can't find the error:

```
    public String getUsernameforID(int id) {
    String statment = "SELECT USERNAME  FROM `BENUTZER` WHERE `ID` = ? ;";
    String username = null;
    try {
        PreparedStatement ps = dbCommunicator.getStatment(statment);  // HERE : NULL POINTER EXECTION
        ps.setInt(1, id);
        ResultSet rs = dbCommunicator.readFromDB(ps);

        if (rs.first()) {
            username = rs.getString("USERNAME");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBManager.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return username;
```

I think it's the statement ... but how can I find this out?
I get a Null Pointer Exeption.

Edit : 
my getStatment-method:

```
    public PreparedStatement getStatment(String st) {
    connect();
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    try {
        ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(st);
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(DBCommunicator.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
    return ps;
    }
```

The Exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.DBCommunicator.getStatment(DBCommunicator.java:107)
    at test.database.DBManager.getUsernameforID(DBManager.java:359)
    at dbtestdrive.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

Comment: NullPointerException.. where?

Comment: also attach the original exception

Comment: Voting to close as 'no longer relevant'.

Comment: The NPE originates from the getStatement() possibly the connection is null. Something fails silently in conenct() perhaps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Although this question may have been solved, here's a little bit on how to go about debugging given an stack trace.

In this case, the stack trace is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at test.DBCommunicator.getStatment(DBCommunicator.java:107)
    at test.database.DBManager.getUsernameforID(DBManager.java:359)
    at dbtestdrive.Main.main(Main.java:25)
```

What this shows is that in the `test.DBCommunicator.getStatment` method, a `NullPointerException` was thrown at the location of line 107 of `DBCommunicator.java`.

Furthermore, the `getStatment` method was called from line 358 of `DBManager.java` which is in the `DBManager.getUsernameforID` method.

Therefore, the first place that should be checked is what is going on at line 107 of `DBCommunicator.java`.

Although there are no line numbers in the code snippet given, one can presume that a `NullPointerException` occurred in the following line:

```
ps = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(st);
```

There's one thing that is fairly common about `NullPointerException`s -- they generally arise when method calls are performed on an `null` reference. Invoking a method on an object that doesn't exist will throw a `NullPointerException`.

In the above code, one can expect that the `connection` variable is actually `null`, rather than having a `Connection`.

This should lead to trying to track down why the `connection` variable is `null` rather than having a valid connection to the database that is initialized.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably because your query is failing, try changing it to:

```
String statment = "SELECT USERNAME  FROM `BENUTZER` WHERE `ID` = ?";
```

Your original query had a trailing semi-colon, which is illegal. This could have caused a nullpointerexception to be thrown up at a later stage, I would advise you to post the contents of your exception.

EDIT:

```
dbCommunicator.getStatment(statment);
```

Should be:

```
dbCommunicator.getStatement(statment);
```

You're misspelling 'statement' as 'statment', which is fine for a variable name, but not when referring to a method :)

Comment: no .. that was not the problem :(

Comment: So paste your exception, or at least the line number that's throwing it

Comment: unfortunately its not the error :S

Answer (score 0):

```
//Ending ";" inside the string, is not neccessary.
String statment = "SELECT USERNAME  FROM `BENUTZER` WHERE `ID` = ? ;";
```

Instead of:

```
PreparedStatement ps = dbCommunicator.getStatment(statment);

PreparedStatement ps = dbCommunicator.prepareStatement(statment);
```

That's what I have using oracle.