# Null pointer exception on insert into database java

Tags: java, sql, nullpointerexception

Hi I have this method below which should insert values into my database. However I am getting a Null Pointer Exception on the PreparedStatement line

```
   public void insertReservation(String name, String phone, int size, String date, String time, String additionalRequirements, String memberID, String themeID) throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException {

        try {
            String strQuery = "INSERT INTO reservation VALUES (?, ? ,?, TO_DATE(?, 'dd-MMM-yy'), ?, ?, ?, ?)";
            PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);/
            stmt.setString(1, name);
            stmt.setString(2, phone);
            stmt.setInt(3, size);
            stmt.setString(4, date);
            stmt.setString(5, time);
            stmt.setString(6, additionalRequirements);
            stmt.setString(7, memberID);
            stmt.setString(8, themeID);
            results = stmt.executeQuery();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }//end try
    }
```

Am I inserting this correctly into my database? I am not sure why I am getting this null pointer exeception error.

Comment: If you don't tell us anything about the exception nobody can help.

Comment: Not really sure why you're getting a nullpointer exception, but check out [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1023835/why-am-i-getting-a-null-pointer-exception-from-this-java-code).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`conn` is `null`, print its value.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know but try this

`String strQuery = "insert into reservation(ColumnName1, ColumnName2 ,ColumnName3,) values(?,?`,?)";

and at the end it will be only execute();
like this `stmt.execute();`

`executeQuery();` statement works with select query Only

Secondly have you described conn value in constructor or method in which ever class you are using the query if you have than assign it like this conn= SqlConnection.ConnecrDb();

below is the SqlConnection Seperate class i have created

```
public class SqlConnection {

    Connection conn=null;

    public static Connection ConnecrDb(){
        try
        {
        Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver");
        Connection conn= DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:Test","","");
        return conn;
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Hope it will help you